# In java can we return different values with every call?

Tags: java, return, call

If I want a method to return three different values repeatedly each time the method is called (without passing those values as a parameter), is it possible?
For example 
1st call to method returns 3
2nd call returns 6
3rd call returns 5
and then this pattern repeats.How could we achieve that?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the method has access to instance field of some kind which can keep track of the number of times the method has been called

Answer (score -1, accepted):

better if you use an static field for this task:
for example, inside your class:

```
private static int myindex=0; //should start at 0
private static int[] myres={3,6,5};
public int method(){ //also static?
    int res = myres[myindex];
    myindex++;
    if(myindex>=myres.length)myindex=0; 
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question was a little unclear… but maybe this might work according to your question? This is just an example below:

```
public int ex;
public int test(){
    if(ex == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    if(ex == 2){
        return 2;
    }
    // and so on
}
```

Then when you call it, you can change ex to something, by doing: ex = (value);

Other than that, there's no other way to make it do something different each time you call it that I know of